# InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' at invalidPipeArgumentError

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to extract a string value from the Observable using the pipe and map, how ever I always got in the end an empty string. I hope that someone can help me to understand the reason behind this issue.

I have an http service that get a file from the back-end:

```
getFiles(url: string, idProject: number, docProject: string): Observable<any> { 
return this.http.get(`${this.hostUrl}${url}/${idProject}/${docProject}`); 
  }
```

I call the getFiles(...) like that:

```
  showFile = false;
  fileUploads: Observable<string[]>;
.
.
.
showFiles(enable: boolean) {
    this.showFile = enable;

    if (enable) {
this.uploadService.getFiles('/projets', this.service.getProjet().idProjet,
  'documentProjets/pv/'//+ td.nomTypeDoc +'/getallfiles')
            .pipe( 
                  map( response => {
                  return response.slice(
                         response.indexOf("files"), 
                         response.lastIndexOf("?"))
                         })).subscribe(
                           (data) => {
                            this.fileUploads=data
                            console.log(data)},
                           (error) => console.log(error));
}
}
```

The result before the Map is:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pv/files/file1.jpg?projetId=563, http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pv/files/file2.jpg?projetId=563
```

and after the MAp is: an empty array.

The HTML:

```
<button class="button btn-info" *ngIf='showFile' (click)='showFiles(false)'>Hide Files</button>

<button class="button btn-info" *ngIf='!showFile' (click)='showFiles(true)'>Show Files</button> 


<div [hidden]="!showFile">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Liste des fichiers</div>

    <div *ngFor="let file of fileUploads | async">  
      <div class="panel-body">
        <app-details-upload [fileUpload]='file'></app-details-upload>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why I get as result an empty value ' ' and this is the error from my consol:

> ListUploadComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for
>   pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>       at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:3981)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy
>   (common.js:4590)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._subscribe
>   (common.js:4580)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe.transform
>   (common.js:4562)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ListUploadComponent.html:10)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:10692)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10457)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You’re subscribing and using the async pipe. Do one or the other, not both. Also use the $ notation for observable streams

Comment: Is showFiles called in ngOnInit (or alternatively ngOnChanges / ngDoCheck)? These lifecycle hooks are called before the component renders, hence need to be used to define the `fileUploads$` observable before render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The async pipe takes an Observable and subscribes for you in the template and unsubscribes for you on component destruction. Keep to the convention of using a $ on the end of observable streams variables.

The following

```
<div *ngFor="let v of values$ | async">
  {{v}}
</div>
```

is equivalent to

```
<div *ngFor="let v of values">
  {{v}}
</div>
```

where in your ts file you do this

`this.values$.subscribe(values => this.values = values)`

---

In your example you can either remove the async pipe from the template or remove the subscription and assign  the stream.

```
this.fileUploads$ = this.uploadService.getFiles('/projets', this.service.getProjet().idProjet,
  'documentProjets/pv/'//+ td.nomTypeDoc +'/getallfiles')
            .pipe( map( response => {
                  return response.slice(
                         response.indexOf("files"), 
                         response.lastIndexOf("?"))
                         }))
```

If you need to console.log for debugging use the tap RxJS pipeable operator.

---

### Update - after debugging steps

The tap operator does not affect the stream (it can be used for side effects like navigation or logging) so it tells you **exactly** what the next operator in the pipe stream is getting...an array of strings. So type for this as follows...

```
this.fileUploads$ = this.yourService.pipe(
    // tap(console.log),
    map((responseUrls: string[]) => {
        return responseUrls.map((url: string) => {
           // some function that 
           // uses string methods
           // or regex
           // to return what you
           // want e.g.
           return url.slice(
               url.indexOf(‘files’),
               url.indexOf(‘?’)
           )
        })
    })
    // }),
    // tap(console.log)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, the issue is no longer exist however the this.fileUploads$ is undefined, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Remember I’ve changed your variable name from fileUploads to fileUploads$ (because it’s an observable stream), so replace `fileUploads: Observable<string[]>;` with `fileUploads$: Observable<string[]>;` and also in the template. If there are any further issues use `tap` operator and log to check and make sure values are coming out of the `getFiles()` observable.

Comment: Yeah i changer the name of it as you did, and even I called showFiles(--) in ngOnInit () I still have the issue of the empty array. I used tap as you said before and after. I apdated my post to include the getting results in before and after the map.

Comment: @Nick I’ve updated my answer. Notice I’m using string methods within an array map.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,your explanation and how to use nested map, it's working now. thank you once again.