# How to use the data of subscribe() somewhere else?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
onKeyUp(event: any): void {
  this.technologiesService.getTechnologies(event.target.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.myData = data;
    });
}
```

The output of `data` is:

[image]

I would like to declare `data` as property, so that I could use it somewhere else. As you see, I have tried it with `this.myData = data` and `myData` is defined like this on the top of my class: `myData = [];`.

This is how I try to use `myData`:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let data of this.myData | async" [value]="data.technology">
  <span>{{ data.technology}}</span>
</mat-option>
```

But I get the following errors:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't subscribe and use the async pipe - do one or the other. The async pipe subscribes for you (and unsubscribes on component destruction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' at invalidPipeArgumentError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349252/invalidpipeargument-for-pipe-asyncpipe-at-invalidpipeargumenterror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of subscribe or async pipe not together. it should be:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let data of myData" [value]="data.technology">
  <span>{{ data.technology}}</span>
</mat-option>
```

when using subscride.
and if you don't want to use subscribe but async, it should be:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let data of myData | async" [value]="data.technology">
  <span>{{ data.technology}}</span>
</mat-option>
```

ts:

```
onKeyUp(event: any): void {
  this.myData = this.technologiesService.getTechnologies(event.target.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this.myData is not async, so no need for the async pipe

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let data of myData" [value]="data.technology">
  <span>{{ data.technology}}</span>
</mat-option>
```

will fix it.

However, I would advice to instead make the observable an instance variable.

```
onKeyUp(event: any): void {
  this.myData = this.technologiesService.getTechnologies(event.target.value)
}
```

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let data of myData | async" [value]="data.technology">
  <span>{{ data.technology}}</span>
</mat-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let data of myData | async" [value]="data.technology">
  <span>{{ data.technology}}</span>
</mat-option>
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *how* this code solves the problem.

Comment: don't use this in the html because no need to use this in the html for global variable